# Boost Threads and Boost Asio

Tags: multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I'm studying Boost Threads and Asio (asynchronous input/output), and I wrote the following example to put some concepts together.

```
class Worker {
  private:
    boost::asio::io_service&     m_ios;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer  m_timer;
    unsigned                     m_cycles;
    unsigned                     m_time2wait;
    std::string                  m_threadName;

  public:
    Worker(boost::asio::io_service& ios,
           unsigned cycles, unsigned time2wait, const std::string& name);
    ~Worker ();
    void start ();
    void run ();
    void stop ();
};


Worker::Worker (boost::asio::io_service& ios,
                unsigned cycles, unsigned time2wait, const std::string& name)
: m_ios(ios),
  m_timer(ios, boost::posix_time::seconds (1)),
  m_cycles(cycles),
  m_time2wait(time2wait),
  m_threadName(name)
{
  logMsg(m_threadName, "is starting . . . ");
}

Worker::~Worker()
{
  logMsg(m_threadName, "is ending . . . ");
}

void Worker::start()
{
  logMsg (m_threadName, "start was called");

  m_timer.expires_at (m_timer.expires_at () +
              boost::posix_time::seconds (m_time2wait));
  m_timer.async_wait (boost::bind (&Worker::run, this));
}

void Worker::stop()
{
}

void Worker::run()
{
  if (m_cycles > 0)
  {
    logMsg (m_threadName, "run # ", m_cycles);
    --m_cycles;
    m_timer.expires_at (m_timer.expires_at() +
                        boost::posix_time::seconds(m_time2wait));
    m_timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Worker::run, this));
  }
  else {
    logMsg (m_threadName, "end of cycling");
  }
}

void run_threads (boost::asio::io_service& io_srv)
{
  Worker worker_1(io_srv, 5, 2, "worker 1");
  Worker worker_2(io_srv, 5, 4, "worker 2");
  worker_1.start();
  worker_2.start();

  boost::shared_ptr <boost::thread> worker_Thread_One (
    new boost::thread (boost::bind (&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_srv)));

  boost::shared_ptr <boost::thread> worker_Thread_Two (
    new boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_srv)));

  worker_Thread_One->join();
  worker_Thread_Two->join();
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  boost::asio::io_service ios;

  run_threads(ios);

  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to have some threads working in parallel, each one doing its work via a specific object. The example apparently seems to work, but I have the feeling that I'm wrong mixing threads and Asio (bad design). Is it the right way to have threads working together with Asio (one io_service for multiple threads)?

How are the threads objects and the “worker” objects “bound” together? I think that they aren't as I would. For example, if I instantiated two objects and two threads I have the expected output. If I instantiated two objects and one thread the output of the program is the same.

(The logMsg is a simple cout wrapper with a mutex to synchronize the output operations.)

Comment: When you ask a question try to keep it informative.

Comment: code looks sane. I would probably use a system_timer instead of a deadline_timer. deadline_timer will do a bunch of calendar work while system_timer just works in "ticks"

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks correct, but it's unnecessary to use Asio in this case. Asio + threads is most useful when you use `io_service` as a work queue for your thread pool. Look into `io_service::post` if you want to use it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

The `asio::io_service` is just a system task dealer, it hold a task queue, and deal with it, you need not use it like this, you should create a thread with your own function which include `io_service::run()` .
The threads and `io_service` can be one to one, or many to one.